# How to show txt file in PHP with ID Post for name file

Tags: php

1. I have `.txt` file, namely "104.txt", and I save in my hosting like this:
   http://example.com/files/104.txt
2. I have post with ID Post: 104

If I use this code to show `txt` file in my theme, it's fine work:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/104.txt" );
?>
```

But, If I use Post ID for name file, it don't work:

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/'.$id.'.txt" );
?>
```

MY QUESTION:
How to resolve to show `txt` file in PHP with ID Post for name file? Thanks

Comment: `echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/$id".".txt" );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/$id.txt" );
```

OR

```
echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/$id".".txt" );
```

OR

```
echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/files/".$id.".txt" );
```

Note:-

Reference:- [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)